Unable to load XML Configuration file into ClassPathXmlApplicationContext even it dose exist
I am attempting to create a bean in Spring application but encounterd IOException while loading XML configuration file into ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.
Test Class Code :
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/satwik/spring/config.xml");
        Employee employee = (Employee) context.getBean("employee");
        System.out.println(employee);
    }

}

Unable to determine why i got this exception, config.xml file is clearly inside classpath (com/satwik/spring) and i provided same while creating ClassPathXmlApplicationContext as seen in above code.
Project classpath :

But i got below IOException:
    at com.satwik.spring.Test.main(Test.java:11)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/satwik/spring/config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 13 more
    ... 13 more

I also tried just keeping config.xml instead of full classpath, But got the same IOException.
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");


Please copy and paste the code and error message into your question rather than posting screenshots.

Hi just made changes to above question can you review it once more. Thanks

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext by default looks for resources in following folder: src/main/resources/.
I think this already answered question will be helpful Spring cannot find bean xml configuration file when it does exist
